# Reference 2 collection in 1 field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Is it possible to have more than 1 reference in a field. If not, is there anyway good way to make it?

I tried this one: (2 reference in productStaff)

```
var productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
    index: true
},
productNumber: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
},
client_id: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Client',
    required: true
},
receiveDate: {
    type: Date,
    required: true
},
paymentDate: {
    type : Date
},
deadline: {
    type: Date,
    required: true
},
remark: {
    type: String,
    default: null
},
productStaff: [{
    staff: {
        type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Staff'
    },
    assignment: {
        type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Assignment'
    }     
}],
productItem: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'ProductItem',
    default: null
}],
registrationDate: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
}
```

});

But i got this error when adding the data:

Error:  "Product validation failed: productStaff: Cast to Array failed for value \"[ { staff: '594b63b184e6290c386baa3f',\n    assignment: '594b63b184e6290c386baa3f' },\n  { staff: '594b63b184e6290c386baa3g',\n    assignment: '594b63b184e6290c386baa3g' } ]\" at path \"productStaff\""

I'm made it this way because I need to save the staff who will do the product with their corresponding assignments.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think it is beause that you may be passing array as stringified. Please check its type or JSON.parse(productStaff) before saving it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply :) 

this is the sample data in productStaff i tried saving using postman:

"productStaff": [
   {
    "staff":"594b63b184e6290c386baa3f",
    "assignment": "594b63b184e6290c386baa3g"
   },
   {
    "staff":"594b63b184e6290c386baa3h",
    "assignment": "594b63b184e6290c386baa3j"
   }
  ] 

And i got the error I posted above.

Comment: You should parse this array into proper json object  before passing to query.